# Филькина грамота

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение этой поговорки "филькина грамота". Кто такой этот Филька?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такую теорию происхождения нашел в этих ваших интернетах:

> Выражение это, так сказать, царского происхождения. Автором его был царь Иван IV, прозванный в народе Грозным за массовые казни и убийства. Для усиления своей самодержавной власти, что невозможно было без ослабления князей, бояр и духовенства, Иван Грозный ввел опричнину, наводившую ужас на все государство Российское. 
> Не мог примириться с разгулом опричников и митрополит Московский Филипп. 
> В своих многочисленных посланиях к царю - грамотах - он стремился убедить Грозного отказаться от проводимой им политики террора, распустить опричнину. Строптивого митрополита Грозный презрительно называл Филькой, а его грамоты - филькиными грамотами. 
> За смелые обличения Грозного и его опричников митрополит Филипп был заточен в Тверской монастырь, где его задушил Малюта Скуратов. 
> Выражение "филькина грамота" укоренилось в народе. Вначале так говорили просто о документах, не имеющих юридической силы. А теперь это означает также и "невежественный, безграмотно составленный документ".

Comment: >>>Такою теорию происхождения нашел в этих ваших интернетах:

Я правильно понимаю, что в "ааших интернетах" есть другая теория?

Comment: Теорий может быть много, но эта самая распространенная, следовательно, она приближена к правде.

Comment: С теориями понятно, а интернетов сколько?

Comment: Ответ здесь: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Словосочетание "эти ваши интернеты" выражает презрительное отношение тех, кто в Интернете ничего, кроме большой помойки, не видит. Если Вы согласны с этим мнением, то что Вы здесь делаете?

Comment: ТОчно так же, читая только комиксы и глянцевые журналы (они в библиотеках тоже есть), кто-нибудь может с презрением сказать "В этих Ваших библиотеках".

Comment: И еще  - безотносительно к данному вопросу - совсем уж не согласна с тем, что самое распространенное мнение значит самое правильное.